# Adding a current password field to CAS password change request

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, cas

I am attempting to implement a minimum character rotation password reset policy with CAS 6.2.7 and Thymeleaf. Since password hashing is a thing, this check must be conducted before the password request is sent to the server. As a result, I need a current password field as part of the password reset view.

The model used for this is the PasswordChangeRequest in the cas-server-support-pm-core module of CAS. This model has a password field and a confirmedPassword field. I need to either modify this model to include a currentPassword field, or somehow link my own model to the form and send them both together.

I have tried both of these options with the help of the guidance found at https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/docs/cas-server-documentation/webflow/Webflow-Customization-Extensions.md. I'm not very well versed in Spring WebFlow and suspect that I am not even close.

Is there any way to accomplish this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component that ultimately attempts to change the password is an implementation of `PasswordManagementService` that does this:

```java
   boolean change(Credential credential, PasswordChangeRequest pcr) 
              throws InvalidPasswordException {
        ...
    }
```

If you design your own custom service, you can implement the `change()` method, and there, you have access to the original password using the `credential` that would then be casted down to `UsernamePasswordCredential`.

A custom implementation usually has the following outline:

```java
@Configuration("MyPasswordConfiguration")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CasConfigurationProperties.class)
public class MyPasswordConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordManagementService passwordChangeService() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Misagh. As I understand it, the change request holds the new password and confirmed new password. Does the credential object come from an identity resource such as a database? If so, this will not work for my case. The old password is stored in a hash. As a result, I cannot perform a Levenstein difference on the old password and new password to make sure the minimum character change threshold is met.

Comment: No it does not come from an identity resource.